# Prevent out-of-proc server shutdown while it has loaded in-proc server object instances

Tags: winapi, com

I have an application which uses an out of process COM server to access a COM object created by an in-proc COM server. This means that the out of process COM server has to load the in process COM DLL to create the final object which it would then return.

For example:

```
// Create an object which resides in the out of process COM server
container.CoCreateInstance("HelperServerProcess");
// Grab a reference to an object which resides in an in process COM server DLL, 
// hosted by the out of process COM server
object = container.GenerateResults();
// Release the object instantiated by the out of process server
container = NULL; // or return, or go out of scope, etc
// This call will fail, because the out of process server has shutdown unloading
// the inproc DLL hosting <object>
object.DoStuff();
```

However, once the container object is released, the final server process reference (in CoReleaseServerProcess ) is released, and the server shuts down. This results in an E_RPC_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE error when trying to use the result object. At the same time the in-proc DLL hosted in this EXE server still has outstanding objects and therefor returns S_FALSE from CanUnloadNow.

I think adding IExternalConnection to the EXE server 's class factory to manually do reference counting on the remote references will not help, because the objects registered by the DLL in-proc server will use the DLLs class factory and try using IExternalConnection on this factory. Also, if the server spawns interactive child objects in its process space it wouldn't trigger IExternalConnection either way.

It also isn't possible to modify the DLL's reference counting to use CoAddRefServerProcess  / CoReleaseServerProcess as the DLL doesn't have access to the container's shutdown code in case it triggers the last release, and third party DLLs can't be changed anyhow.

The only method which I can think of which might work is adding a loop after the server refcount hits zero, which calls CoFreeUnusedLibraries, and then somehow enumerates all loaded COM DLLs and waits until none are loaded and ensures the server refcount is still zero. This would leak processes if a loaded DLL does not implement CanUnloadNow correctly, and involves messing around with low level COM implmentation details which I would like to avoid.

Is there any easier way to ensure that the COM objects instantiated by class factories of in-proc servers keep the process alive, or to enumerate the class factories of DLLs loaded into the current process and query them for the number of references?

Update: Another method which may work, but sounds very much like the sort of things you aren't supposed to do: intercepting every spawned thread in the process, registering a CoInitialize hook via CoRegisterInitializeSpy, and adding server process reference for every thread that currently has COM initialized.

Comment: The proper term for this is "bug".  If you can't get the server fixed then you'd better hang on to an interface reference.  Contact the author or vendor of the server for advice.

Comment: @HansPassant: I can fix the server, it is currently using CAtlExeModuleT to manage its lifetime. This class however only keeps the server alive as long as instances of COM objects it has created via its own class factory exist. I just cannot figure out how to extend the Lock / UnLock behavior to also respect the private refcount of the DLLs dynamically loaded via CoGetClassObject / CoCreateInstance which the DLLs use in DLLCanUnloadNow.

Answer (score 2):

The out-of-proc EXE can delegate the DLL object rather than return it directly. Have `GetResults()` return an object that the EXE implements, and have that implementation use the DLL internally as needed.  This way, the EXE will not be released until the caller releases the EXE's object, thus keeping the EXE's own refcount active. The EXE's object can implement the same interface that the DLL object implements.  This way, the caller does not know (or care) that delegation is being used.

Comment: That would only work if there is a generic way to intercept all possible calls on the subobject that can create / return further subobjects, otherwise the tree of objects which must be wrap would grow indefinitely, and runtime defined IDispatch methods also could escape. This would also require mapping all wrappers to real object to deal with backreferences.

Comment: If the object in question exposes access to sub objects, yes. The entire tree would have to be wrapped so that the EXE's own refcount is maintained.

Comment: +1 and such wrapping can be automated by implementing `IMarshal` on the root object (although that'd be a tedious task).